# How is readxl misreading an excel xlsx file and how to fix it?

Tags: r, excel, xlsx, readxl

I am trying to download and read an xlsx file from 2016 Kansas State faculty counts.

https://www.k-state.edu/pa/faculty/demographics/total/index.html

When the tibble is created, some numbers do not match the original excel file.

```
url <- "https://www.k-state.edu/pa/faculty/demographics/total/t2016.xlsx"

download.file(url, destfile = "t2016.xlsx",  mode = "wb")

library(readxl)

kansas_state <- read_xlsx("t2016.xlsx", skip = 165, col_names = FALSE)

gender <- kansas_state[1:4]
names(gender) <- c("COLLEGE", "N", "Male", "F")
gender
```

I am reading the very last table in the excel sheet, with totals for each college.

[image]

Then if you open the excel file and look at the last table "University Totals," some numbers do not match. Such as College of Agriculture, but College of Architecture does...?

[image]

I have also shared the github public link here for an rstudio project on this example:

https://github.com/AdamUArk/r_readxl_example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are hidden sheets in this file, so `read_xlsx()` reads from one of those sheets instead of the sheet you normally see. To read the one you want, add `sheet = 'Totals'` to the arguments of `read_xlsx()`.